# Keras: Why is my testing accuracy unstable?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, supervised-learning

I design and train an Inception-ResNet model for image recognition. The network has learned well from the training dataset. However, the test accuracy is very unstable.

Here are some parameters and important information I have used for learning process:

- The number of training samples: **40,000** images.
- The number of test samples: **15,000** images.
- Learning rate is set to **0.001** for the first **50** epochs, **0.0001** for the next **50** epochs and **0.00001** for the rest.
- Batchsize: **128**
- Dropout rate: **0.2**

After 150 epochs, learning curves, including training loss and test accuracy look like that:

[Training loss and test accuracy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X10e.png)

I tried to increase the batch size. However, it is not the solution to my problem.

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to provide.

Regards,

An Nhien./.

Comment: I would suggest you to decrease the batch size and that too near to 16.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. However, the problem is not solved even after reducing the batch size.